# How to Auto-enable bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I have a BusyBox. After star-up, I always need to do

```
hciconfig hci0 up
```

manually to enable bluetooth. Is there any method to ignore that?

There is one solution I found here, adding

```
[Policy] AutoEnable=true
```

to `/etc/bluetooth/main.config`.
But I couldn't find the bluetooth directory in `/etc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean [this BusyBox](https://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#commands), then your system is probably a very minimalist/customized/embedded one. The actual BusyBox package does not seem to include any Bluetooth functionality at all, so there may be nothing ”standard” to refer to. That is going to make it very difficult to answer your question without getting a much more detailed description of your possibly unique system first.

Since the `hciconfig` command exists, you probably have at least some parts of [the BlueZ suite](http://www.bluez.org/download/) installed: perhaps the old-version`bluez-utils` only.

Note that even with the old versions, `bluez-utils` was only one part of the complete suite, and in the modern 5.x version it is not even offered as a separate part. To me, that strongly suggests that you might need more parts of the BlueZ suite than just `hciconfig` for meaningful Bluetooth functionality, unless you implement the necessary parts in some other way.

But if you just need to run that one command, find out what kind of start-up scripts your system runs, and either add that command to one of the existing scripts in a suitable location, or add an entirely new start-up script of your own for it. How to do that, you ask? Well, it depends on which of the various types of *init system* you are actually using. Even BusyBox apparently supports several types.

Comment: Yes, BlueZ version is 5.xx. but yes I just want to run that one command. My system is using scripts from etc/init.d for start-up. So I wrote a bluetooth.sh and added executable to /etc/init.d. I just have one more question, after adding script to init.d, do I need to add in inittab?

Comment: Adding a script into `/etc/init.d` alone won't automatically execute it at boot. If you have a SysVinit-style set of boot scripts already (or a `systemd`-based system with SysVinit script compatibility enabled), you would need to make a symbolic link in e.g. `/etc/rc3.d/` directory, with a name like `S99bluetooth.sh`, pointing to your script in `/etc/init.d/`. If you have a BSD-style set of start-up scripts, then you might need to add something to `/etc/inittab` to have your script called at boot. Then there is also OpenRC...

Comment: It worked ! After writing bluetooth.sh and chmod u+a bluetooth.sh, I added executable to /etc/init.d and renamed it according to the S* sequence. As on start-up /etc/inittab runing rc scripts(rcS) according to numeric order. Thanks !